# web2py, securely copy remote db to a local machine

Tags: python, web2py

I have a web2py application. I want to add functionality that
privileged users can download/copy database of the app from the remote server to a local machine.
The catch is the db contains sensitive information like login credentials.
How can I modify db entries on the fly while copying  db from the remote server?

Comment: what type of database is it? and why don't you just not include the login credentials table in your export?

Comment: the app is running on GAE. The problem that I also need to change user names all over the db.

Comment: this is why you typically use a user_id as a foreign key instead of a user_name

Comment: yes, I am aware of it, It was done purposefully.

Comment: okay, how can I allow download all but the login credentials tabel?

Comment: alright well maybe clone the whole database and then write a script to eliminate all the bad columns and drop any tables you don't want and run it on the cloned db. or just do a select statement for every table you want to export and exclude any with sensitive info.